# Flutter build correctly TabBarView children

Tags: flutter, dart

On my one of `TabBarView` i have fixed item count for children that i have data into a nested `List`, for example i have `List<Book>' variable which each` Book`is a another`List` as book's pages

```dart
final List<Books> _books;
final List<Pages> _pages;
```

now you suppose i have 5 `book` into `_books` and first index of that, there is `book` with 100 page,

```dart
_book[0] = [
  {
    'contentList': [ ... ],
    'pages':[
      {
        'pageNumber' : 1,
        'pageNumber' : 2,
        'pageNumber' : 3,
        'pageNumber' : 4,
        'pageNumber' : 5,
      }
    ]
  }
];

_book[1] = [
  {
    'contentList': [ ... ],
    'pages':[
      {
        'pageNumber' : 1,
      }
    ]
  }
];

_book[2] = [
  {
    'contentList': [ ... ]
    'pages':[
      {
        'pageNumber' : 1,
        'pageNumber' : 2,
        'pageNumber' : 3,
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

as you can see length of `_book` is 3 and each `_book` has some `contentList` and`pages`, then my `TabBarView` childrent length should be 3 and each child of `TabBarView` should be have `GridView` as list of `contentList`

here when i try to build this structure i get `length` error for `TabBarView`, because each `i` in first `for` run more than `_books` length and it should be `3` not `8` and it depends on `k` in second `for`.

how can i resolve this problem and build correctly child into `TabBarView`?

```dart
TabBarView(
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
controller: _booksController,
children: [
  for (int i = 0; i < _books.length; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < _books[i].contentList.length; k++)
      GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 0,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 1 / 0.4,
            ),
            itemCount: _books[k].contentList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              final title = _books[k].contentList[index].title;
              final page = _books[k].contentList[index].page;
            }),
]),
```

whats correct?

i should be have `3` child into `TabBarView` and into

first child i should be have `5` item in `GridView`,

second child i should be have `1` item in `GridView`,

third child i should be have `3` item in `GridView`,

Comment: I think you should use _books[i].contentList.length in grid view, because books has an index of i and not index of k meanwhile k is books's page/content indext ?!

Answer (score 0):

```
TabBarView(
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
controller: _booksController,
children: [
  for (int i = 0; i < _books.length; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < _books[i]['pages'].length; k++) //edited here
      GridView.builder(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisSpacing: 0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 0,
              crossAxisCount: 3,
              childAspectRatio: 1 / 0.4,
            ),
            itemCount: _books[i].contentList.length, //changed to i from k
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
              final from = _books[i].contentList[index].title; //changed to i from k
              final to = _books[i].contentList[index].page; //changed to i from k
            }),
]),
```